# Handle Error in PDFBox loadNonSeq

Tags: log4j, pdfbox, apache-commons-logging

I Load a PDF using `PDDocument.loadNonSeq(attachment, null);`

The `NonSequentialPDFParser` loggs an Error

```
Feb 23, 2016 5:17:04 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.NonSequentialPDFParser checkXrefOffsets
SCHWERWIEGEND: Can't find the object 13 0 (origin offset 643917)
```

but no Exception gets thrown.

This error has to be handled by our application, what would be the appropriate way to achieve this?

The only solutions I can think of is to write a custom log handler or patch the PDFBox lib to throw an Exception, but both dont seem to be the right way to do this.

edit:

I can't share the PDF file itself since its confidential but the file content from the offset 643917 is:

```
12 0 obj
<< /Creator ()
/CreationDate ()
/Author ()
/Producer ()
/Title ()
/Subject ()
>>
endobj
xref
1 13
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000009 00000 n 
0000148944 00000 n 
0000149041 00000 n 
0000643794 00000 n 
0000149228 00000 n 
0000396801 00000 n 
0000396898 00000 n 
0000397085 00000 n 
0000643509 00000 n 
0000643606 00000 n 
0000643865 00000 n 
0000643917 00000 n 
trailer
<<
/Size 12
/Root 11 0 R
/Info 12 0 R
>>
startxref
644014
%%EOF
```

so he is looking for 13 0 where 12 0 is

Comment: There's probably no solution for this, except rewriting PDFBox so that it is "strict". The problem with PDF is that the specification is extremely complex, and there are tons of files that are formally incorrect. And then, we at PDFBox get bug reports with this text "But it renders with Adobe Reader!".

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Actually PDFBox here is more strict than the specification. In particular it expects the object number to be exactly at the offset and the generation and the `obj` following each time with exactly one space character in-between. The specification is not so strict, it also allows different and even multiple white space characters, even comments are possible.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply @TilmanHausherr, I doubt that there is a simple solution to find these objects somehow since with this errors some of the pages are rendered blank and if I have to rewrite it, I'd rather try to find the object than to reject the whole file

Comment: Please share the PDF... also try with 2.0 which has much better rendering. And have a look at offset 643917 with a tool like NOTEPAD++. It should be "13 0 obj" there but obviously it isn't.

Comment: i tryed to migrate to 2.0 a few months ago but it broke too much of our code so we postponed it, but i think i'll give it a new try since this requirement came up. Also i edited the question with the content of the pdf file. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in the PDF cross reference table:

```
xref
1 13
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000009 00000 n 
0000148944 00000 n 
0000149041 00000 n 
0000643794 00000 n 
0000149228 00000 n 
0000396801 00000 n 
0000396898 00000 n 
0000397085 00000 n 
0000643509 00000 n 
0000643606 00000 n 
0000643865 00000 n 
0000643917 00000 n 
trailer
<<
/Size 12
/Root 11 0 R
/Info 12 0 R
>>
startxref
644014
%%EOF
```

The `1 13` should have been a `0 13`. This results in wrong entries all through the table, object 1 is considered to be free, object 2 is considered where actually object 1 is, ..., an object 13 is considered to be where object 12 is.

Furthermore these cross references are invalid for yet another reason, cf. the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf):

> For a file that has never been
>   incrementally updated, the cross-reference section shall contain only one subsection, whose object numbering
>   begins at 0.
>
> *(section 7.5.4 Cross-Reference Table)*

But the cross references in your document start at 1.